# Pig scripts not found error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running my first pig script ,it is failing with below error. any idea?
I have hortonworks distribution installed on my machine.
I am following steps in the below article.

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_5

> File does not exist:
>   /user/admin/pig/jobs/explain_p1_28-03-2016-00-58-46/stderr at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:71)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:652)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2151) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2147) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2145)

Comment: The error "File does not exist:" is self explanatory.Check for file,path.

Comment: This job file is being created by job iteself. I think I don't have any control over it

Comment: This might be similar: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/17173/file-does-not-exist-error-with-orgapachehivehcatal.html